# JavaのWebアプリでMysqlに接続してクエリを実行するとエラーが発生する

Tags: java, mysql, jax-rs

下記のコードにてMYSQLへ接続し、URL「http://hogehoge/hoge/api/hoge/search?hoge=*」で指定した範囲の結果表示をしたいです。
しかし、例外やエラーが続出していまい、作業がとまっています。
いろいろ調べたりしているのですがよくわかりません。

```
@GET
@Path("search?hoge={hoge}")
public ArrayList<Hogehoge> getHoge(@QueryParam("hoge") Integer hoge){

    ArrayList<Hogehoge> list = new ArrayList<Hogehoge>();
    Hogehoge hoge;

    hoge = new Hogehoge();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/SampleDB040";
        String user = "testmysql";
        String password = "******";

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println(conn.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "select hoge,hoge,hoge,hoge,hoge"
                + " from hoge,hoge,hoge,hoge"
                + " where hoge.hoge = hoge.hoge "
                + " and hoge.hoge = hoge.hoge"
                + " and hoge.hoge = hoge.hoge"
                + " and order by hoge"
                + " and hoge.hoge = "+hoge+"";

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        System.out.println();

        while (rs.next()) {


            hoge = new Hogehoge();

            pref.setHogeCd(rs.getInt("hoge")); 
            pref.setHoge1Name(rs.getString("hoge")); 
            pref.setHoge2Name(rs.getString("hoge")); 
            pref.setHoge3Name(rs.getString("hoge")); 
            pref.setHoge4Name(rs.getString("hoge")); 

            list.add(hoge);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("例外発生:" + e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

下記のClassで実行？されます

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();

        resources.add(Hogehoge.class);

        return resources;
    }

}
```

下記エラー、例外です。長くてすみません。

```
警告: No operation matching request path "/rest-sample/api/pref/1" is found, Relative                             Path: /1, HTTP Method: GET, ContentType: */*, Accept:     text/html,application/xhtml+xml,image/webp,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details. [金 1 23 14:14:35 JST 2015]
警告: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.findTargetMethod(JAXRSUtils.java:415)
at     org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:216)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:91)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:240)
at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.onMessage(CxfRsHttpListener.java:187)
at org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RsServlet.service(RsServlet.java:53)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: 生成されたSQLを直接mysqlで実行すると、正しい答えが返ってきますか？

Comment: はい。正しい答えが返ってきます。しかし、この場合、"+hoge+"の部分を指定した値で設定した場合です。
実際はここにURLで指定した値をいれ、その結果を表示させるプログラムを作りたいです。

Comment: さっと見た限りでは、`" and hoge.hoge = "+hoge+""` を `" and hoge.hoge = '"+hoge+"'"` に直すべきかなとは思いますが、例外スタックトレースがあればちゃんと原因がわかりそうな気がします。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。本文にエラー警告を追記しました。

Comment: 素早い対応ありがとうございます。例外からいえるのは、これは SQL や DB の問題ではないことです。 HTTP アクセスをWebアプリケーションフレームワークもしくはWebサーバがどう振り分けるかの設定が問題です。 URLルーティング設定の部分か、直接 tomcat にアクセスされていないならプロキシ設定が正しくされれば解決するでしょう。ここに落とされた情報の中では、`@Path("search?hoge={hoge}")` の部分になるんですかね、それ以上は今わかりません。

Comment: 正確な回答をするために`getHoge()`が定義されているclassを含むコードを質問文に記載すると良さそうです。私は少しPCから離れる為、即答出来ませんが。。。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。少し変更いたしました。

Answer (score 4):

@Path("search?hoge={hoge}")を@Path("{hoge}")に修正
return null;をListに変えたところ、無事動作しました。

今回の結果は自分のコード確認不足によるものでした。
大変お騒がせしました。

Comment: Effective Javaという書籍からの受け売りですが、Listを返すメソッドが`null`を返すメリットはほぼないので`Collections.emptyList()`を返す癖を付けるのが良いかと思います。(今回は当てはまらないケースですが)